# OK to mix TBB with posix semaphores?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, posix, semaphore, tbb

Is it OK to mix TBB with posix semaphores? I know that this means I'm limiting the number of systems I can run on but beyond that are there any possible bad interactions that I need to worry about it or is it safe to use posix semaphores anywhere I'd use a TBB mutex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes unless it is used to express dependencies between TBB tasks or implies mandatory concurrency. I.e. you never should rely on TBB to provide specific number of threads running simultaneously. And if scheduler is not aware of dependencies between tasks, it can schedule them on the same thread (in case of nested algorithm/wait call) and so deadlock.

It's also not recommended to block inside TBB task at all, it can cause CPUs under-utilization.